# How to assert array values in groovy using script assertion

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I am writing a script assertion to see if a element value contains in the array list and if it does, it passes.

When I print the element:Number, I get like an example `[1,2,3,3]` as array. If Number contains say 3, script has to pass.

I have written below code which is failing, probably because the written value is an array list, how to assert an array value?

```
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent()
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def invoiceNumber= xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Number'}
log.info "$invoiceNumber"
assert invoiceNumber.contains(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `invoiceNumber` is a `Collection` of `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` elements instead of `Integer` elements. This is why the `contains(3)` comparison never returns `true`.

You've to convert array of `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` to array of integers before the `contains()`, you can do it using the spread dot operator an `NodeChild.toInteger()`, so your script must be:

```
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent()
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def invoiceNumber= xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Number'}
log.info "$invoiceNumber"
// convert the array to array of integers
invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber*.toInteger()
// now you can perform the assert correctly
assert invoiceNumber .contains(3)
```

Hope it helps,